# How can I fix Atmel Studio 7 install which is stuck on "initializing environment"?

Tags: atmega, atmel, atmel-studio

**Atmel Studio 7 Install Is Stuck**

I'm attempting to install Atmel Studio 7.  I've tried both the online install and the download then install option and the installer becomes stuck (shown in the image).

**Hardware Shouldn't be A Problem**

I'm running **Windows 10** on an i7 with 8GB ram and a decent Internet connection (20MBPS).

**Possible Issue?**

I do have Visual Studio Community 2013 on my machine (not 2015).  Could that be a source of the problem?

Anyone Else Experience This?

**Any Advice On How To Diagnose or Resolve?**
Do you know of anything to try to diagnose this issue?
Has anyone else had this issue and resolved it?
I've Googled but haven't found any related info. 
[image: atmel studio install is stuck]

**EDIT** 
It seems as if numerous people are running into this problem.

> The **solution** was to simply Cancel the installation and restart the computer.  The
>   installation was locked.  After that, when my computer restarted the installation continued and fixed the issue.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to this site ? This is clearly a computer problem - there are tons of computers who have installed this successfully.

Comment: The only way I was ever able to resolve serious AS7 issues was by  removing windows. -- So, my solution is to light your computer on fire and then buy a new one... Sorry this isn't actually helpful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about a computer problem about installing software and not the day-to-day use of it, or its features.

Comment: @efox29 I wasn't sure about it either, but it's difficult to find the correct place to talk about the installation failing.  This is the world of _modern technology_.  :p If it works, you're fine.  If not...And, often, it does not.  :D

Comment: @daylight your best bet would be ones who know the software well - which would be the atmel forums

Comment: @efox29 Thanks, No problem.  I'll check.

Comment: This question has become popular as numerous people have this problem.  The solution was to simply Cancel and restart the computer.  The installation was locked.

Comment: A better solution might be to get the stand-alone ASF sources distribution, and use it with your own preferred tools for efficiently getting work done.  The unique-tool-per-target paradigm really isn't sustainable even if the tools actually work without issue, which does not appear to be the case here.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yeah, I don't even end up using Atmel studio.  I use Arudino IDE or AVRDude and the gnu toolchain.  It's better to be closer to the metal -- especially with embedded dev.  :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is run this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493 to get a better idea of what is actually failing.